# Multiple Click Controls -- Does a layer have to be added to a map before you can add a control?

Tags: openlayers

This code works fine as is, but it seems to be dependent on the layers being added to the map before the controls are added. Is that always the case or am I doing something wrong?

```
          var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([a,b], {
              hover: true,
              highlightOnly: true,
              renderIntent: "temporary",
              eventListeners: {                      
                  featurehighlighted: make_popup,
                  featureunhighlighted: kill_popup
              }
          });

          var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([a,b,c,d], {
              clickout: true,
              toggle: false,
              multiple: false,
              hover: false
          });

          map.addLayer(a);
          map.addLayer(b);
          map.addLayer(c);
          map.addLayer(d);

          map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
          map.addControl(selectControl);
          highlightCtrl.activate();
          selectControl.activate();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not dependent on the layers being added to the map before the controls are added.  As you can see from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NWrGQ/1/). You can add the SelectFeature control and activate it before adding the layer to the map.

relevant piece of code:

```js
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
    hover: false,
    highlightOnly: false,
    toggle: false,
    renderIntent: "select"
});

map.addControl(selectControl);

selectControl.activate();

map.addLayer(vectorLayer); //<-- layer added at the end
```

Comment: Yes, but when you add another vectorLayer it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/kFdkH/      BTW, I've never heard of jsfiddle-- that is awesome thanks for sharing!

Comment: To tell you the truth i would have never expected the case i put above to have worked. My initial response was going to say YES... seems to be dependent. But after testing the above case, it proved that your question is not ALWAYS the case. That said, I ALWAYS add the layer(s) to the map before adding the layer to the control. How can I expect the selectControl to hightlight a layer that does not exist on the map? That's why the case above surprised me and i was forced to change my original YES answer to NO. But are you asking just out of curiosity? I would just stick to add to map first.

Comment: Well, I have quite a few layers that have hover pop-ups and click abilities, but I wanted to load them asynchronously so they all don't make a bunch of unnecessary calls if the user isn't looking at that data just to keep things a little more speedy. But my problem came, when I wasn't adding the layers the click/hover features didn't work unless I added them before adding the controls.

Comment: I suppose you can load the controls asynchronously at the time of adding the layers (right after).

Comment: @Jonathan, can you add the features asynchronously on the same vector layer vs creating a new one? jsfiddle.net/leewhitbeck/kFdkH/1

Comment: @leewhitbeck Unfortunately, no, they are distinctly different features that need to remain independent.

Comment: @capdragon Thanks, I did end up resorting to loading them asynchrously after I added the layers.